# Entity Framework Core migration from a console app not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am writing a simple console application to test some EF Core code.

I added the `entityframework.commands` package.

```
install-package entityframework.commands -pre
```

The connection string is correct and tested, but when I execute

```
Update-Database
```

from the package manager I get the following error.

> No DbContext was found. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

Of course, I have a context, just one in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entityframework.commands` is ancient. Use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` instead.